# Are browsers making request on unused fonts included by @font-face?

Tags: css, fonts, webfonts

### Question

Are browsers making requests and downloading **all** the files specified by `@font-face` declarations or **only the ones which are referenced throughout the stylesheets**?

### Example

Let's say I have 3 `@font-face` declarations:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'A';
  src: url('http://fonts.com/font-a.woff2') format('woff2');
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'B';
  src: url('http://fonts.com/font-b.woff2') format('woff2');
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'C';
  src: url('http://fonts.com/font-c.woff2') format('woff2');
}
```

And then all my styles are:

```
body {
  font-family: 'A';
}

h1 {
  font-family: 'B';
}
```

Will font `C` be requested by the browser or not? Is it standardised somewhere in the specification?

Comment: You can check it by yourself. Open inspector and go to the netwirk tab.

Comment: @3rdthemagical I asked the question after observing that in Firefox Developer Tools. I posted the question, cause I was interested is that standardised behaviour across all browsers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Yes** - unused fonts are requested on some old browsers, e.g. IE8 and older.

How ever, almost all modern browsers today do not make additional requests for unused imports. https://css-tricks.com/preventing-the-performance-hit-from-custom-fonts/

Consider `importing` these fonts from Google, `Lato`, `Roboto` and `Raleway`

```
@font-face {
 font-family: 'A';
 src: url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato');
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'B';
  src: url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto');
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'C';
  src: url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway');
}

body {
  font-family: 'A';
}

h1 {
  font-family: 'B';
}
```

And with the following HTML markup

```
<body>
  <h1>Lorem ipsum</h1>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolar sit amet</p>
</body>
```

You can inspect the requests made by the browser in the developer tool, e.g. in Google Chrome, press `F12` and open the network tab.

[image: Requests by browser]

Notice that only `Roboto` and `Lato` were requested, although `Raleway` was imported in the CSS file.

Comment: I observed the same behaviour in Firefox Developer Tools and it got me curious, but I was unable to find and resource which would confirm it works like that in all browsers. If your answer is correct, can you point to some resource confirming that?

Comment: Thanks. Though including a link to css-tricks article inside the quote looks like the quote comes from that article. I was unable to find the quoted text in that article. The only text in this article which I found confirming that is "The first idea I saw was Dave Rupert's tests on only loading `@font-face` on large screens. Turns out if you use `@font-face` but don't ever apply that `font-family`, the font won't be downloaded. Pretty smart, browsers."

Comment: I have a question, in HTML codes above, it does not indicate which fonts to be used. Why browser chooses Roboto and Lato, not Raleway?